# Rxjs subject switch map to call another observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to call another observable on every emitted value in the subject.

My problem now is the first emitted value to the `subject` triggers the `switchMap` and calls the `confirmCsvUpload(...)`, but every next emitted value does trigger the `switchMap` but not the `confirmCsvUpload(...)`.

Can someone figure out why its not calling the function?

```
// Subject
private _confirmCsvUpload = new Subject<{ account: Account, previewData: PreviewData[], previewId: string }>();

// Subscription to the Subject 
this._confirmCsvUpload.pipe(
  switchMap(previewData => this._uploadCsvService.confirmCsvUpload(previewData.account, previewData.previewData, previewData.previewId))
).subscribe();

// Function which emits value to the subject (Not the function who gets called in the switchMap())
confirmCsvUpload(): void {
  this._confirmCsvUpload.next({ account: this.account, previewData: this._previewData, previewId: this.getPreviewIdFromRoute() });
}
```

Comment: Share complete code

Comment: Is `this._uploadCsvService.confirmCsvUpload(previewData.account, previewData.previewData, previewData.previewId)` by itself an observable?

Comment: @Benny its an function which returns an observable

Comment: @zainhassan What code do you need? i think the ``this._uploadCsvService.confirmCsvUpload(...)`` doesnt matter

Comment: @MarcelSauter ok that's good. In that case I advise to share a minimal app on Stackblitz that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Nex time for sure i will create an stackblitz app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i try to replay you scenary with:

```
  private _confirm$ = new Subject();
  private _destroy$ = new Subject();
  ngOnInit() {
    this._confirm$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroy$),
        tap((v) => console.log('[SUB]', v)),
        switchMap((v: any) => this.secondCall())
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  secondCall() {
    console.log('[SECOND CALL]');
    return of();
  }

  callSub() {
    console.log('[NEXT VALUE]');
    this._confirm$.next('value');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroy$.next(null);
    this._destroy$.complete();
    console.log('[NG ON DESTROY]');
  }
```

Console log with 2 call:

```
[NEXT VALUE]
[SUB] value
[SECOND CALL]
```

-- second time:

```
[NEXT VALUE]
[SUB] value
[SECOND CALL]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think my problem is the service function which returns the observable, but with your example i exclude that my problem is the switchMap.